# Converting sharet_ptr<Derived> to shared_ptr<Base>

Tags: c++, type-conversion, shared-ptr

I have a

```
class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>{....}

class B: public A{....}
```

later in code, I'm doing this:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> Construct(....){
    class_field=std::make_shared<B>(...);
    
    return class_field->shared_from_this();
}
```

With this code, I want to make sure that the object of B gets destroyed once current class is destroyed, as well as when the object in client function goes out of scope.

Is this correct way to handle this? Is there a better way to get shared_ptr from shared_ptr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purpose of `shared_from_this` is to have access to shared pointer from class itself.

You should not use this outside of class, so as a result your code in question is simply an overkill. it should be:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<A> Construct(....){
    return std::make_shared<B>(...);
}
```

Comment: wow, I never thought to check whether shared_ptr<B> is directly convertible to shared_ptr<A>

Comment: smart pointer are written in such way that they are as similar to raw pointer as possible, so implicit conversion up provided.